# Bad security practice to load rendered HTML via AJAX for XSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, xss

I have a web page with some user content displayed on initial page load. There's a button that can trigger further page loads (somewhat like Twitter's infinite scrolling). The Django template that renders the original page is also used to render content for infinite scroll (partial view). The server sends formatted HTML via AJAX that can be easily inserted into my existing page like this:

```
$(new-Html).insertAfter($('existing-content'))
```

With this option, I can **reuse** the existing template to render my content. Is it worth the convenience and can I assume that escaping at Django's end covers me from XSS? It's this [jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521) that worries me. It can be dangerous stuffing all that HTML into a selector `$(..)`

Or, should I use JSON as response type and carefully craft all user content as text nodes with jQuery? This is a lot more work & error prone since I'll be duplicating the template rendering to a large extent. Even though this route *appears* a lot more safer, it's difficult to maintain two redundant rendering methods, one via template, other via JS.

*update* : I considered using innerHTML as suggested in one of the comments but not sure about that either : http://www.slideshare.net/x00mario/the-innerhtml-apocalypse (Mario Heiderich on mXSS)

Answer (score 0):

> The Django template that renders the original page is also used to render content for infinite scroll (partial view).

Therefore you are safe. If all you are doing is rendering content that you have control of and already trust for your initial page load, then there will be nothing malicious in the page source to be rendered. In this case as you are loading form a trusted source, if there was any malicious code rendered that would cause [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) then this would be an issue with the AJAX service that supplies the source, not the JQuery that renders it.

The ticket you refer to is regarding `XSS WITH $(LOCATION.HASH) AND $(#<TAG>)` which is different to what you are doing (and has also been marked as fixed).

Comment: `1.` Original rendering is done by browser engine BUT subsequent content is rendered with the help of jQuery selector. Hence the issue. `2.` The ticket mentions that using selector is dangerous with user input and they don't plan to patch it for every possible input. It's up to the developer to ensure that all inputs are properly escaped. If you read all the comments, you'll realize there are open issues with `$()` & XSS. It can be used to create elements which would be unsafe when done inadvertently.

Comment: @click as you are rendering from a trusted source (i.e. the same source that rendered the initial page), you should be safe.

Comment: I mention in my question that the site contains user content. I wouldn't trust that. The trouble arises when jQuery interacts with the user content using `$()`. Read more here http://ma.la/jquery_xss/

Comment: @click: My answer is based on the assumption that you are properly escaping this user content as you are displaying it on your original HTML page. If the user added something malicious here, it would likely to be rendered on your original HTML page if not properly escaped - the AJAX request does not increase this risk. Yes there are attacks such as mXSS, but these only apply if you are attempting to _sanitize_ a subset of HTML for display. If you are not doing this, then your AJAX request is as safe as the original page load.

Comment: @click: Need any further info or clarification?

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

Use this line before passing the HTML into the jQuery it will remove any scripts (including onmouseover etc.) that are included in the HTML:

```
var cleansed = str.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gmi, "");
cleansed = cleansed.replace(/\bon\w+\s*=[\s\S]*?>/gmi, ">");
```

I still say that the jQuery/Django method is the ideal method. The above line will clean the content of scripts before you add it to the DOM.

**Previous**

Django should escape anything it's passing into that line of jQuery. So long as you aren't using an eval() statement anywhere in there, cross-site scripting shouldn't be a concern. I'd say it's more practical to continue the way you're going.

Comment: It's this jQuery ticket : bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521 that makes me wonder if it's safe to put all that HTML inside `$(...)`

Comment: actually, jQuery's .html() method runs eval() if it sees any scripts. it would be safer to use innerHTML to prevent such un-wanted execution, but even there you can get the dreaded onmouseover-style attacks that hit twitter a while back. i would just not store html period.

Comment: The innerHTML apocalypse : http://www.slideshare.net/x00mario/the-innerhtml-apocalypse

Comment: i would suggest you just read a blog post or two on preventing XSS and try hacking yourself to see if there is indeed a problem to be fixed...

Comment: I posted this question after going through a good number of blog posts, slideshares & OWASP write-ups. I have not found a definitive answer to my query. From what I've gathered, I'd disagree with your advice on hacking around to avoid XSS as someone who's new to this. Even an experienced person can hack to find a problem, BUT it's a lot more difficult to say is there's no XSS issue here.

Comment: @aecend Try `$("<img src='/' onerror=alert('xss');>")` in a browser window with jQuery injected. Your cleanse won't fix it.

Comment: @click, the change I just made will remove that with or without quotes now. And btw, you'll need to pass the HTML through the RegEx before passing it into the jQuery.